# Beautiful input-output of messages in command line (in C)

Tags: c, input, output

I wrote a client-server chat for command line, but can't realise a beautiful input of messages in client part.

I create a thread, then I use fgets function with stdin stream to transmit messages to server. Then I print messages this way:

```
printf("Client -> Server: %s", fgets(&bufferData[0], sizeof(bufferData), stdin));
```

Input (server returns the message back):

```
Hello
Client -> Server: Hello
Server -> Client #500: Hello
```

I want to leave only last two lines.

If I do like that:

```
printf("Client -> Server: ");
fgets(&bufferData[0], sizeof(bufferData), stdin);
```

I get that:

```
Hey
Client -> Server: Server -> Client #456: Hey
```

How to make it just like that?

```
 Client -> Server: Hey
 Server -> Client #456: Hey
```

Client code with send realisation:

```
    DWORD thID;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, HandleReadThread, (LPVOID)socketDescriptor, NULL, &thID);
    printf("Client -> Server: ");
    while (1)
    {

        fgets(&bufferData[0], sizeof(bufferData), stdin);

        if (!strcmp(&bufferData[0], "quit\n"))
        {
            send(socketDescriptor, &bufferData[0], strlen(&bufferData[0]), 0);
            printf("You just left the chat. Good bye\n");
            //break;
            running = false;
            int retwait = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 500);
            if (retwait == 0)
            {
                printf("WaitForSingleObject error : Error code: %d", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
            if (shutdown(socketDescriptor, SD_BOTH) != 0)
            {
                printf("Shutdown SHUT_RDWR error");
            }
            break;
        }

        FD_ZERO(&writeSet);
        FD_SET(socketDescriptor, &writeSet);
        tv.tv_sec = 5;

        if ((retVal = select(socketDescriptor + 1, NULL, &writeSet, NULL, &tv)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Send non-blocking error");
            break;
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(socketDescriptor, &writeSet) != 0)
        {
            if (send(socketDescriptor, bufferData, strlen(&bufferData[0]), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("Send error");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please provide a [mcve], the exact input, the desired output and the actual output.

Comment: We appreciate that you've attempted to stick to essentials, but you've been too zealous. You've omitted the code that creates the problem.You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `printf("Client -> Server: %s", fgets(&bufferData[0], sizeof(bufferData), stdin));` - What happens if `fgets` fails and returns null?

Comment: I didn't clearly get how it can be failed. If I send empty message (just \n), it returens \n, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printf is buffered.  You need to flush the buffer

```
printf(...)
fflush(stdout);
fgets(...)
```

**Edit** Note that fgets gets the newline.  This needs to be removed before transmission.

Comment: Unfortunately it has blocked receiving messages from server to client

Comment: Here I meant I want to see my printing after line "Client - > Server: *print here* "

But now it looks like:

my message //printed in command line
Client -> Server: my message
Server - > client: my message

Comment: Is the server->client on the same thread or on a different thread?  Are you going through a switch or running completely on localhost or on a loopback connector?

Comment: It's the same thread (server receives client socket and send a message back through this socket (and to all clients in list also)).
I'm testin on localhost and connect with 127.0.0.1 to server

Comment: If you're doing client-server using sockets, they need to be in separate processes - not threads.  Just pop up 2 cmd prompts and run the client and server separately.  You can then extend that to two separate machines.or VMs.

Comment: Of course I have 2 different projects: server.c and client.c and run it in 2 different windows (and a few for clients). Server has to receive quit-message and it has treatment in server part (remove from client list, client number count, etc)

Comment: And your server receive gets blocked after adding fflush?

Comment: Nope, it's still working but I don't like how my input look like in cmd. it's 3 line: 1st - where I type, 2nd - client->server transmission and 3rd - server->client message (received back)

Comment: @GeorgeZ.Added comment to the answer - may fix your 3 line problem.